# loading screen appears after jquery alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

I'm trying to create a loading screen for it to appear when the form is being submitted, it works great except on Safari, the problem is that if you were to click enter or submit an alert appears but when you click okay for the alert to go away the loading appears because of the submit event and doesn't go away. I've tried numerous this but i cant seem to figure it out, i'm a beginner in jquery.

To summarize, on safari after alert, loading screen appears when it's not suppose too and doesn't go away.

Preferably I would like for the loading screen to appear only when the form is being submitted. or the alternative is for the loading screen not to show in a safari browser.

```js
<script>
      var form = document.getElementById('formID'); // form has to have ID: <form id="formID">      
      var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    
      if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) {
        if (ua.indexOf('chrome') > -1) {
    
        } else {
    
          form.noValidate = true;
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { /*listen for form submitting */
            if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
              event.preventDefault(); /*dismiss the default functionality*/
              alert('Please, fill the form before you submit'); /*error message*/
              $("#formID").attr("id", "form");
              $(".circularG1").addClass("active");
              $(".circularbrg").addClass("active");
            }
          }, false);
        }
      }
    </script>
    <!--loading screen appears while form submit's-->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#formID').submit(function() {
          var pass = true; //some validations
          if (pass == false) {
            return false;
            $(".circularG1").addClass('active'); //hides loading if clicked
            $(".circularbrg").addClass('active'); // hides loading if clicked
          } else {
            $(".circularG1, .active").removeClass('active'); //shows loading if clicked
            $(".circularbrg, .active").removeClass('active'); // shows loading if clicked
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
    <!--^--END--^-->
    <!-- 3. Add this script for Function of Hamburger Menu -->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".icon").on("click", function() {
          $("header .nav ul").toggleClass("open", 200);
        });
    
      });
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>

 <div class="circularG1 active">
 <div id="circularG_1" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_2" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_3" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_4" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_5" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_6" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_7" class="circularG"></div>
 <div id="circularG_8" class="circularG"></div>
</div>
 <div class="circularbrg active"></div>
    
<form id="formID" class="Form" action="" method="post">

  <input name="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="50" min="2" required>

  <input name="lname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name"  maxlength="50" min="2" required>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: I posted an answer that can help you solve this, but I realized I didn't exactly answer your question. So (in your eventListener above, what is the purpose of these two lines after alert): $(".circularG1").addClass("active"); $(".circularbrg").addClass("active"); ?

Comment: @MohammedAlsaedi    after the alert you'll see                     $("#formID").attr("id", "form");
$(".circularG1").addClass("active");
$(".circularbrg").addClass("active");  this code was an attempt to hide the loading screen by adding class active and the loading screen gets activated when clicked on the form by submit so i thought if i changed the name of the form it would stop the loading screen from appearing

Comment: So my question is, what are circularG1 and circularbrg? Are these the loading screen? If so, the lines don't belong here because they will apply right after the alert.

Comment: i asnwered you and clicked enter by accident and then reedited my comment thank you for the comment, i'm not that good at jquery so would it be possible if you can tell me where i can put that code for to stop the reload screen from appearing @MoAlsaedi

Comment: The answer basically recommends you remove the (alert line), so just follow the answer below. This way, you will ensure that behavior is the same on all browsers. Once you do that, we can see if the loading window still appears erroneously.

Comment: it works now! @MoAlsaedi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to resolve this issue is to remove the alert line altogether and use a different method. For example, add a div inside your form html:

```
<div id="form-message"></div>
```

Then in your jQuery, replace the alert line with:

```
$('#form-message').text('Please, fill the form before you submit');
```

This is better in terms of usability as actual alerts are rarely (if ever) used on websites these days.

Hope this helps!